# How to remove object from object array by object key name?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to remove an object from this object array individually by its key name. So if I wanted to remove `item1` I would call a function or something similar and it would remove it completely.

```
var list = [{item1: 'Foo'}, {item2: 'Bar'}];

removeObjectByKeyName(item1);
```

I expect the object array after deletion to be `[{item2: 'Bar'}]`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `filter` to filter the array element with no property name `toRemove`

```js
var list = [{
  item1: 'Foo'
}, {
  item2: 'Bar'
}];

var toRemove = 'item1';
var result = list.filter(o => !(toRemove in o));

console.log(result);
```

---

With `removeObjectByKeyName` function. The first parameter is the key to remove and the second is the array.

```js
let list = [{
  item1: 'Foo'
}, {
  item2: 'Bar'
}];


let removeObjectByKeyName = (k, a) => a.filter(o => !(k in o));

let result = removeObjectByKeyName('item1', list);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this function will do what you need:

```
var list = [{item1: 'Foo'}, {item2: 'Bar'}];

function removeObjectByKeyName(list, key) {
  return list.filter(item => !Object.keys(item).find(k => k === key) )
}

removeObjectByKeyName(list, 'item1') // [{item2: 'Bar'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `hasOwnProperty`

```js
var list = [{
  item1: 'Foo'
}, {
  item2: 'Bar'
}];

var toRemove = 'item1';
var result = list.filter(o => !o.hasOwnProperty(toRemove));

console.log(result);
```